# How to change Leaflet marker color on mouseover?

Tags: geojson, markers, leaflet

I'm having a hard time figuring out why the Leaflet method `setstyle` will change the color of a polygon but not the color of my markers.

Polygon works fine:

[image: Polygon]

But the markers won't change colors:

[image: Markers]

I want to be able to mouseover a marker and changes its color.  It seemed like setStyle would do this.  But I keep getting `layer.setStyle is not a function`

I'm using Angular and Leaflet together to make the map (I'm using the angular-leaflet-directive).

Here's the mouseover part of the code:

```
$scope.$on("leafletDirectiveMap.geojsonMouseover", function (ev, leafletEvent) {
        pointMouseover(leafletEvent);
    });

    function pointMouseover(leafletEvent) {
        var layer = leafletEvent.target;
        layer.setStyle({
            weight: 2,
            color: '#666',
            fillColor: 'white'
        });
    }
```

When the marker get's moused over, it fires `pointMousever` which then tries to invoke setStyle on the LeafletEvent.target.  I've console.logged the LeafletEvent and there is indeed the Target part of it:

[image: Target]

Why would setStyle work for the polygon and not for the marker?  What's the way to change the marker's color?

Comment: You should check out [Leaflet.StyleEditor](http://dwilhelm89.github.io/Leaflet.StyleEditor/) on GitHub.  It took me a while to figure out how to get the demo to work, but 1) click the Style tool, 2) click the marker, 3) ***key point***... change the icon setting to something other than default, 4) select color. Voila!  Pretty slick.

Comment: And the Leaflet StyleEditor does its magic by giving the icon a Mapbox URL of this form: http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/marker/pin-m-circle+ffc871.png, where ffc871 is the hex color string. Apparently it can be any six-digit hex string! But probably this is best done using MakiMarkers, which seems to have been designed for this purpose: https://github.com/jseppi/Leaflet.MakiMarkers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you can't do that because a marker uses an image to render.

[image]

I think you'd need to grab the [icon class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon) of your marker and change the "iconUrl" attribute to whatever new image you want.

Source: [Leaflet API Reference](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html)

Hope that helps,

DR

Answer (score 9):

Figured it out thanks to some documentation reading.

The polygon in leaflet responds to `setStyle` but the marker can be changed using `setIcon`

[Documentation for setIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-seticon)

Answer (score 5):

See Kyle Pennell's Answer :

> The polygon in leaflet responds to setStyle but the marker can be
>   changed using setIcon

You can use following lines :

```
// create custom icon
IconStyleOne = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/image1.png'
        });
IconStyleTwo = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/image2.png'
        });

// ...

//Create empty geojson with mouseover and mouseout events
geojson_feature = L.geoJson(false, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: IconStyleOne});
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature,layer)
            {
            layer.on("mouseover",function(e){
                layer.setIcon(IconStyleOne)
            });
            layer.on("mouseout",function(e){
                layer.setIcon(IconStyleTwo)
            });
            }
}).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: Kyle Pennell has a great question and answer here ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without having to create a million different icon images if you use CSS.

1. Add the marker
2. find the backgroundcolor attribute for the css and change it.

Here it is:

```
var marker = L.marker([50,-20], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);
marker.valueOf()._icon.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
```

Comment: So this only changes the background color? Can you give an example of what that would look like for a typical icon?

Comment: @LarsH, Yes, this would change the background (put a green square behind the blue teardrop icon). Unfortunately, you can't just change the fill color. As others have pointed out, the icon does not have a  color property. It is just an image (jpg or png) and you have to swap the whole image.