# Changing circle marker color in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I use the following code in order to change the fillColor of a marker within my leaflet-client, as suggested on this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124928/20297

```
var marker = marker = L.circleMarker(latlng, myMarkerOptions).addTo(map);
marker.valueOf()._icon.style.fillColor = 'green'
```

However when I execute this, I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I also tried to directly change the markers color:

```
marker.fillColor = 'green'
```

which simply does absolutely nothing.

My browser is an Opera 66. However I also checked FireFox to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change fill color of `L.circleMarker` dynamically, you can use [the `setStyle` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#path-setstyle), inherited from the `L.Path` class.

To change marker fill color to green:

```
marker.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});
```

The example you are referring to is for regular `L.marker` marker with user defined icon. It's also not politically correct since it uses internal object properties that might change from version to version. Politically correct method for changing icon background color would be to use `className` option of `L.icon` instance.

Comment: Your edit turned this answer into a treasure. I was sure relying on the internals is a bad thing, however I couldn´t find any resource to set the color once the marker was created. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For change color circleMarker use `NameCircle.setStyle({color: 'color name'});`

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/xd3Lmoqb/

[image: circleMarker]

```
circle2 = L.circleMarker([5,8]  ).addTo(map);
    
circle = L.circleMarker([2,1] ).addTo(map);
 
circle.setStyle({color: 'green'});

circle2.setStyle({color: 'red'});
```